# linking pdf file in beamer latex without switch off first document slide

Tags: hyperlink, href

I use \href to link my pdf file in my presentation. The problem is, it change my first document slide to the linked pdf. So, i have to reopen my slide again to continue my presentation. How can I make the linked pdf document open in new pdf document? (like open a new tab/window?). So, i don't have to reopen my slide presentation. Here my commands:

```
\begin{proof}
\href{run:./proof 3.1.4.pdf}{proof 3.1.4.pdf}  
\end{proof}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hyperref` manual says:

> ### 4 Additional user macros
>
> ...
>
> ```
> \href[options]{URL}{text}
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The optional argument `options` recognizes the hyperref options
> `pdfremotestartview`, `pdfnewwindow` and ...

Thus, `pdfnewwindow` is what you need. This option can also be given as a package option, acc. to section 3.9, in order to have a global effect.